# What's Wrong with the usage of thread and mutex

Tags: c++

I wrote an test project for learning the c++ thread, but some error happened in my program.

the code is sample that a class provide a function that can add data to container and the data will be print in thread, and the data which has been printed will be removed from container.

that is the code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager() 
    {
        const auto expression = [&]()->void {return threadProc(); };
        thread(expression).detach();
    }
    ~Manager() {}

    void addData(int num)
    {
        if (m_data.lock())
            m_data.data.push_back(num);
    }

private:
    struct
    {
        vector<int> data;
        unique_lock<mutex> lock()
        {
            return unique_lock<mutex>(m);
        }
    private:
        mutex m;
    }m_data;

    void threadProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (m_data.lock())
            {
                for_each(m_data.data.begin(), m_data.data.end(), [](int num)
                {
                    cout << num << endl;
                });
                m_data.data.clear();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Manager manager;
    manager.addData(1);

    system("pause");
}
```

when it runs, it will shows

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um851.png)

Could you please tell me where is the problem? thanks!

Comment: What problem? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what "some error" means?

Comment: sorry, I have edited for uploading the picture of error info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporary `unique_lock` returned by `lock()` is destroyed right away, unlocking the mutex. Access to `data` is not in fact protected from concurrent access. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: I think the unique_lock will be moved to the return value by move constructor, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it will be. What will then happen with that return value? At what point, exactly, do you believe this returned instance of `unique_lock` is destroyed, and why do you believe that?

Comment: I think the return instance of unique_lock will be destroyed at the end of "if",such as if(m_data.lock()){...},the returned instance of unique_lock will be destroyed at the "}"

Comment: because the unique_lock will be destroyed at the end of scope of unique_lock

Comment: You think incorrectly. A temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression - in this case, at the closing paren of `if ()`, before the body of the statement is reached.